# I upgraded from 2.1.9 to 2.2.7 but css and javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, css

I tried to upgrade using these commands :

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.7 --no-update

composer update

rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Everything ran successfully but css and javascript files are not working in the back- and front-end.
I checked the .httaccess files and ran content deploy:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ar_SA -f
```

[image: Frontend]

Comment: Try to desploy static content before cache clear and flush

Comment: run bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f (without the language).

Comment: I try deploy before cache and deploy without language and nothing change

Answer (score 0):

Maby it is something that has to do with symlinks. Try changing the following in the `app/etc/di.xml` file

```
<virtualType name="developerMaterialization" type="Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Factory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="strategiesList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

to:

```
<virtualType name="developerMaterialization" type="Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Factory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="strategiesList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

If this is not working can you give us the output of the var/log/system.log file.

Comment: I Do change it but nothing work

Comment: What is the output of your logs in file var/log/system.log?

Comment: [2018-12-19 14:56:10] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.panel.wrapper' element cannot be added as child to 'header.container', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-12-19 14:56:10] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'head.polyfill' element cannot be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-12-19 14:56:10] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'head.components' element cannot be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't exist [] []